# Call Python function w/ values from a locally set up module

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a module named `my_math` set up with basic functions inside, such as:

```
def triangle(base, height):
    return base*height/2
```

When I `import my_math` in the terminal (python3) and call the function w/ parameters like this it gives me the answer:

```
>>> import my_math
>>> my_math.triangle(2, 8)
8.0
```

However, if I place the values for `base` and `height` inside or outside in the function in the `my_math` module and try to call the function using those values, I receive an error:

```
# my_math.py
base = 3
height = 4

def triangle(base, height):
    # base = 3
    # height = 4
    return base*height/2

# trying it at the interpreter prompt
>>> my_math.triangle(base, height)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'base' is not defined. Did you mean: 'False'?
```

How can I make the code use the values defined in the module instead?

Comment: Well, yes. Of course `base` doesn't mean anything *locally*. Hint: Why did you have to write `my_math.triangle`, and not simply `triangle`? Do you see why the same logic applies to `base` and `height`?

Comment: I edited your question to [remove noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) and the attempted image link (it wasn't working, but you [should not use images for code or errors anyway](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)). For additional guidance, please read [ask].

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Simply writing triangle(x, y)  I receive a Traceback and NameError: name 'triangle' is not defined.  But when I write,  my_math.triangle(x, y) I get the answer.

Comment: Exactly. See how that's the same problem you have with `base` and `height`? See how you already know how to solve that problem? So....

Comment: Just call it as `my_math.triangle(my_math.base, my_math.height)`

Comment: Maybe you could read these doc. to understand better the `scope` rules: https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/   and official doc. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to import all variables and methods from the module, like so:

```py
from my_math import *

triangle(base,height)
# returns 6
```

Alternatively, you could statically reference the variables directly from the module:

```py
import my_math

my_math.triangle(my_math.base, my_math.height)
# returns 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, and it's usually better to just put in the parameters each time.

You could set default parameters for your functions like this:

```
def myFunction(value1 = 10, value2 = 10):
   pass
```

this will set the values to 10 if nothing is passed in for them: [more on this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function-argument#:%7E:text=Python%20Default%20Arguments)

But as far as I'm aware, this really doesn't work and it's better practice to pass in your arguments each time.

Answer (score -1):

In Python, variables are defined only locally unless otherwise specified. This means that in the scope of your function, those variables are not defined. Declaring them as globals should fix your issue:

```
global base
base = 3
global height
height = 4

def triangle():
    global base
    global height
    # base = 3
    # height = 4
    return base*height/2
```

Comment: Putting the globals inside the method will override the parameters. This is bad practice, it makes the parameters superfluous.

Comment: This you are right about, I was more focused on preserving asker's code. I will edit.